# Pip ProxyError Cannot connect to proxy on CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, centos7

I'm having trouble installing libraries using pip in my freshly installed CentOS 7 (7.9.2009) server.

I installed python 3.8.3 and upgrade the pip right away to the latest version 21.0.1.

Already exported my `http_proxy` and `https_proxy settings`,

```
http_proxy=http://<creds>@10.XXX.XX.XX:XXX
https_proxy=https://<creds>@10.XXX.XX.XX:XXX
```

But when I try to install libraries via pip I get this error.

```
[root@localhost downloads]# pip3.8 install pandas --proxy https://user:pwd@10.XXX.XXX.XXX:808
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', timeout('_ssl.c:1091: The handshake operation timed out'))': /simple/pandas/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', timeout('_ssl.c:1091: The handshake operation timed out'))': /simple/pandas/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', timeout('_ssl.c:1091: The handshake operation timed out'))': /simple/pandas/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', timeout('_ssl.c:1091: The handshake operation timed out'))': /simple/pandas/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', timeout('_ssl.c:1091: The handshake operation timed out'))': /simple/pandas/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandas
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pandas
```

I tried the verbose mode to check.

[image: verbose pip error]

I tried to check tha pandas url via curl if i can access it, and yes I can.

```
[root@localhost downloads]# curl -I https://pypi.org/simple/pandas/
HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established
Proxy-agent: CCProxy

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 381742
Cache-Control: max-age=600, public
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'; sandbox allow-top-navigation
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
ETag: "zPB5FsC5JkZZm1ZnKHnuUw"
Referrer-Policy: origin-when-cross-origin
Server: nginx/1.13.9
X-PyPI-Last-Serial: 9182431
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Wed, 03 Feb 2021 07:44:51 GMT
X-Served-By: cache-bwi5146-BWI, cache-sin18034-SIN
X-Cache: HIT, HIT
X-Cache-Hits: 1, 1
X-Timer: S1612338291.161041,VS0,VE1
Vary: Accept-Encoding, Accept-Encoding
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
X-Frame-Options: deny
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies: none
```

I also tried to `wget` the latest pandas file in the said repository and I was able to download it.

```
[root@localhost downloads]# wget https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/11/1c/b0bc154996617eae877ff267fcf84e55e6c6808dbade0da206f0419dd483/pandas-1.2.1.tar.gz#sha256=5527c5475d955c0bc9689c56865aaa2a7b13c504d6c44f0aadbf57b565af5ebd
--2021-02-03 10:47:24--  https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/11/1c/b0bc154996617eae877ff267fcf84e55e6c6808dbade0da206f0419dd483/pandas-1.2.1.tar.gz
Connecting to 10.XXX.XXX.XXX:808... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 5459053 (5.2M) [application/x-tar]
Saving to: ‘pandas-1.2.1.tar.gz’

100%[============================================================================================>] 5,459,053    418KB/s   in 13s

2021-02-03 10:47:39 (399 KB/s) - ‘pandas-1.2.1.tar.gz’ saved [5459053/5459053]
```

Am I missing something here? Im thinking of server setting that is causing this. Or is it just the proxy is not working?

Comment: error shows problem with your proxy server. Why do you use it? What settings did you exported?

Comment: http_proxy=http://<creds>@10.XXX.XX.XX:XXX
https_proxy=https://<creds>@10.XXX.XX.XX:XXX

Comment: Is it realy the proxy? But why does my curl and wget gets thru if its the proxy?

Comment: error shows `'Cannot connect to proxy` so problem makes `proxy`. Did you try to use `pip` proxy with `http` instead of `https` ? `--proxy http://....`. And in `wget`, `curl` you don't set manually proxy but they choose from `http_proxy` or `https_proxy` and you don't know which one they use.

Comment: put proxy settings in question - more people will see it.

Comment: BTW: `pip --help` shows `--proxy <proxy>  Specify a proxy in the form [user:passwd@]proxy.server:port.` and there is nothing about `http` or `https` - so maybe you should use `--proxy user:pwd@10.XXX.XXX.XXX:808` ?

Comment: I tried `--proxy http://...` but to no avail. I also tried `--proxy user:pwd@10.XXX.XXX.XXX:808` also to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Was able to resolve this by reverting to an older version of pip. Upon installation of my python3.8 version to this **new server**, I immediately **upgraded** my pip as recommended by pip itself.

It so happen I also have an **old server** which also has a python3.8 installation. Upon seeing the recommendation of pip to upgrade, I also upgraded my pip in my **old server**.

After encountering this problem in my **new server** and trouble shooting for literally 2 days, I checked my **old server** if my pip is still working after upgrade, and it turns out I'm now encountering the same problem which concludes that it must be the latest ***pip v21.0.1*** is causing the problem which makes me unable to connect to the proxy I'm using.

**SOLUTION**

Reverting back to the default pip version that my python v 3.8.3 comes with.
I did this by first uninstalling the upgraded pip.

```
pip3.8 uninstall pip
```

After confirming the uinstallation, I reverted to the default pip version that comes with my python3.8 installation.

```
python3.8 -m ensurepip
```

This installed the old version (v19.2.3) of pip which comes with my python installation.

and lo and behold, everything works as expected now!